# How to get the selected row values in table in angular?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular5

**HTML Code**
I am using a reactive form, well when the user selects any checkbox, and then clicks on Assemble button, i want to get the selected values. Can anyone help me?

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" fxFill appearance="outline">
 <!-- Checkbox Column -->
 <ng-container matColumnDef="select">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
       <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="value" 
         (change)="$event ? masterToggle() : null" 
         [checked]="selection.hasValue() && isAllSelected() == true"
         [indeterminate]="selection.hasValue() && !isAllSelected()">
       </mat-checkbox>
     </th>
     <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
        <mat-checkbox (click)="$event.stopPropagation()" 
          (change)="$event ? selection.toggle(row) : null" 
          [checked]="selection.isSelected(row) == true">
        </mat-checkbox>
     </td>
     </ng-container>

     <!-- Name Column -->
     <ng-container matColumnDef="Name">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let dataSource"> {{dataSource.name}} </td>
     </ng-container>

     <!-- Symbol Column -->
     <ng-container matColumnDef="Modified">
         <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Modified </th>
         <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let dataArray"> {{dataArray.modifiedAt}} </td>
     </ng-container>   
      <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
      <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" 
        (click)="selection.toggle(row)">
      </tr>
</table>
</mat-sidenav-container>
   <mat-dialog-actions align="end">
     <button mat-button (click)="onCancel()">Cancel</button>
     <button mat-button type="submit" (click)="onAssemble()" 
        [disabled]="!assemblyForm.valid"> Assemble
    </button>
</mat-dialog-actions>
```

Answer (score 4):

Made some changes in HTML

```html
<ng-container matColumnDef="select">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
    <mat-checkbox  (change)="$event ? masterToggle($event) : null" [checked]="selection.hasValue() && isAllSelected() == true" [indeterminate]="selection.hasValue() && !isAllSelected()">
    </mat-checkbox>
  </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
    <mat-checkbox (click)="$event.stopPropagation()" (change)="$event ? selectRow($event, row) : null" (change)="$event ? selection.toggle(row) : null" [checked]="selection.isSelected(row) == true">
    </mat-checkbox>
  </td>
</ng-container>
```

*and added some function in .ts file*

```js
isAllSelected($event) {
  const numSelected = this.selection.selected.length;
  const numRows = this.dataSource.data.length;
  return numSelected === numRows;
}
masterToggle($event) {
  if ($event.checked) {
    this.onCompleteRow(this.dataSource);
  }
  this.isAllSelected($event) ?
    this.selection.clear() :
  this.dataSource.data.forEach(row => this.selection.select(row));
}

private selectRow($event, dataSource) {
  // console.log($event.checked);
  if ($event.checked) {
    console.log(dataSource.name);
  }
}

onCompleteRow(dataSource) {
  dataSource.data.forEach(element => {
    console.log(element.name);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display the output in HTML screen Just add the following line in your HTML code

```
{{selection.selected|json}}
```

To view in the console-

```
console.log(this.selection.selected)
```

Answer (score 0):

Include the following code in your html

```
<mat-checkbox color="primary" 
    [checked]="value[i]"(change)=functionToMaintainCheckedList()>
</mat-checkbox>
```

In your function(TS File)

```
functionToMaintainCheckedList() {
    if (this.value[i]) {
        this.value[i] = false;
        // Splice the value From your array 
    } else {
        //Add that value to your array
        this.value[i] = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain? what are you trying to do?

Comment: In Your Value array you simply maintain what rows are to be added and in the array you would finally like to display on assemble you push or splice the array accordingly

Comment: It didn't worked, as the value which you passed is undefined.